# How do I document functions that have multiple parameter order options in JsDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a function for removing event handlers from an `EventEmitter` class. It looks something like this:

```
EventEmitter.prototype.remove_handler = function(event_name, handler) {
    if(arguments.length < 2) {
        handler = event_name;
        event_name = null;
    }

    // ...
};
```

The function can either be called with an event name and a handler, or just the handler. If the event name is present, the handler is removed from that specific event, otherwise it's completely removed from the event emitter.

How do I document such scenarios in JsDoc? In this case I could certainly just document the parameters as they appear and note that "event_name can be omitted, in whice case (etc...)", but I can certainly imagine scenarios where that would be impossible.

Comment: Just explain it in plain text in the general comment section for the function, and declare the parameter that is optional as such.

Comment: @Mörre: Yes, as I said in my question, that works in *this* case, but what about a function with a more drastic variety of parameter options? For example, a function that accepts two *completely* different sets of arguments. You'd need to document it almost as if it was two functions, and you'd need at least two `@param` lines for each parameter. That is the sort of situation I'm curious about.

Comment: As I said, explain it in the comment section in plain text, and leave out @param if that complicates things. Or really HAVE two functions. I'm not so sure what I'd say to functions that have completely different argument options... I'll defer judgment until I see a concrete case and then I'll only judge that case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `@also` tag to provide multiple method signatures:

```
/**
 *
 * @param {String} event_name
 * @param {Function} handler
 *
 * @also
 *
 * @param {Function} handler
 */
EventEmitter.prototype.remove_handler = function(event_name, handler) {
```